# How do you choose the version of typescript for your node visual studio project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, typescript1.8

I have a node console application in VS2015 Update 2. Some Typescript features are missing and I'd like to tell my project to use TS1.8. Where do I do that? I am also using Resharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I do that? I am also using Resharper.

TypeScript ships with nightlies : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/07/27/introducing-typescript-nightlies.aspx

## More:

Documentation on how to use it with visual studio https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Dev-Mode-in-Visual-Studio

From that link :

[image]